# Checking file size in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, filesize

I am trying to find the size of a file and if it is greater than 0, I want to do some stuff.
I have this code:

```
set file="C:\AnalyzerCheck\loaded.txt"
set minbytesize=0
if exist %file% (
FOR /F "usebackq" %A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%~zA
if %size% GTR %minbytesize% (
    //do stuff
) else (
    //do stuff
)
```

However, I am getting this ouput/error when I run the script:

> C:\AnalyzerCheck>set file=C:\AnalyzerCheck\loaded.txt
>
> C:\AnalyzerCheck>set minbytesize=0
>
> file~zA was unexpected at this
>   time.
>
> C:\AnalyzerCheck>FOR /F "usebackq" file~zA
>
> C:\AnalyzerCheck>

How do I fix this error?

Edit:

New error:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%~zA
```

have two errors: You must not use /F option (neither "useback" option) because you want not to read the file CONTENTS, but just process the file NAME. Also, if this command is inside a Batch file, the A replaceable parameter must have two percent signs:

```
FOR %%A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA
```

Comment: I suggest using ("%file%") instead of (%file%) in case the file name has spaces. Your FOR command failed for me because my file names have spaces. Adding the quote marks let it with file names that have spaces.

Answer (score 2):

**Within a script,**

This Command:

```
    for /f %%A in ("myfile.txt") do set size=%%~zA
```

Or This Command:

```
    set "filename=myfile.txt"
    for %%A in (%filename%) do echo.Size of "%%A" is %%~zA bytes
```

Or This Command:

```
    set "filename=myfile.txt"
    for /f %%A in (%filename%) do set size=%%~zA
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@echo off
cd C:\MyFolder\
set file="MyFile.txt"

set maxbytesize=0

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% GTR %maxbytesize% (
    //do stuff
) ELSE (
    //do stuff
)
```